ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time version (8.1.2) is older than compile-time version (8.4.0) MacOS 14.0 Sonoma
Context - I'm not a Python developer by trade and have always developed in the cloud, but now need to make a simple Python script that uses Pycurl to download data. I've been struggling with getting pycurl to work on my mac. I've tried every variant of the answers listed-
MAC OS ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time version (7.37.1) is older than compile-time version (7.43.0)
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time version (7.79.1) is older than compile-time version (7.84.0)
libcurl link-time version (7.76.1) is older than compile-time version (7.86.0)
Mac Os X: "libcurl link-time version (7.43.0) is older than compile-time version (7.51.0)"
https://github.com/binux/pyspider/issues/472
https://gist.github.com/enfont/70b87caca1a16fabb8c9e9e4e142f099
NOTHING WORKS !
I have managed to setup a folder with pyenv to isolate versioning etc.
Brew is set to a newer version-
brew info curl ==> curl: stable 8.9.0 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]
curl version is always the older version
curl --version curl 8.1.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0) libcurl/8.1.2 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/3.3.6 zlib/1.2.12 nghttp2/1.55.1
I also have a specific version of curl 8.4.0 in the folder where pyenv is activated and have PATH, LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS set
export PATH="$(pwd)/curl-8.4.0/bin:$PATH" export LDFLAGS="-L$(pwd)/curl-8.4.0/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib" export CPPFLAGS="-I$(pwd)/curl-8.4.0/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
Also had setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH as suggested in some SE posts.
What's worse is that there are no solutions out there for macos Sonoma. How do i get Pycurl to stop throwing this error ?

Not directly related to your question, but can you not use a native Python http module like requests or httpx?

I might be able to. I have a working curl request that works to download data. Are there any major differences between using these vs pycurl ?

The API is very different, but they are all ultimately http clients and you should generally be able to accomplish the same thing.

Thank you for the response. I will try them out.

I got the same issue, I fixed it by installing pycurl from the GitHub
 git clone https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl.git
 cd pycurl
 python setup.py install
 python -c "import pycurl"


